# Trying to double an array and hash values in python

Tags: python, arrays, hash, double

I am creating a hash function and am confused about doubling the size, rehashing the values, and then proceeding with the new table. What I've done is create a separate array to store just the keys so I can rehash it (since the self.table stores both the key and value) but when I run it, it creates the new table but the hashing of the values ends up not happening. Anyone have any ideas?

```
class Hashing(object):

def __init__(self,size):
    self.array_size = size
    self.table = self.array_size * [None]
    self.size = 0  
    self.keyList = []

def _hash(self,key):
    pos = key
    print key, " ", pos % self.array_size
    return pos % self.array_size

def doubleSize(self):
    self.array_size = self.array_size*2
    self.table = (self.array_size) * [None]
    doubleHash = Hashing(self.array_size)
    i = 0
    for each in self.keyList:
        print "Each ", each
        doubleHash[each] = i
        i += 1
    print "double", self.table    


def __setitem__(self,key,value):
    if self.size > self.array_size/2:
        self.doubleSize()
    pos = self._hash(key)
    while True:
        if self.table[pos] is not None:
            if self.table[pos][0] == key:
                self.table[pos] = (key,value)
                return
        else:
            self.table[pos] = (key,value)
            self.keyList.append(key)
            self.size += 1
            return
        pos = (pos + 1) % self.array_size
```

and main (for lack of a better word with Python...)

```
    from Hashing import Hashing

    myHash = Hashing(4)
    i = 0
    myArray = [1,12,13,11]
    for each in myArray:
        myHash[each] = i
         i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem stems from this line: `doubleHash = Hashing(self.array_size)`.
You're creating an entirely new `Hashing` object when you should just be changing the values in self. The `doubleHash` object is discarded at the end of the `doubleSize` method when `doubleHash` goes out of scope.